# Sending Data from .java Class to Main Activity using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I my app , I need to send the data of a variable (Longitude) to the Main Activity ,but am i getting a null value when trying to print the value .Here is the piece of code.

```
try
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(sd.toString()); 

            _longitude=getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

            exif.saveAttributes();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("ParkingInfo._longitude", _longitude);

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
and here is the method declaration for getApplicationContext()


private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

is it because the getApplicationContext() is returning a null value am getting a null value,if so what should i must replace with it so that I can get my values in the MainActivity

Comment: its quite hard to understand your code

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` is fine but instead of this you can use `YOUACTIVITY.this` and you might be getting null because variable `_longitude`might be null.

Comment: Is the code posted in a activity class?.

Comment: ok what else u want ,
in simple terms how can I pass the value from a .java class (not an Activity) to the MainActivity.java.
what ever I tried ,am getting a "null".

_longitude is present in (ParkingInfo.java) ,how can I successfully
receive the value in MainActivity.java using Intents.

Comment: @ Nitin but i tried sending direct values ,it still fails.

Comment: @ Raghunandan no its a background .java class without any activity.

Comment: @N.Nihar create a method and create an instance of that class and call that method

Comment: @N.Nihar from where to use this java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a Plain .java class create a method

```
public double returnData()
{
      ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(sd.toString()); 
      _longitude=getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
      exif.saveAttributes();

    return _longitude;// assuming _longitude is double
}
```

In MainActivity

```
 MyJavaClassName my = new MyJavaClassName();
 double value = my.returnData();
```

Answer (score 0):

change `getApplicationContext()` to `this` and delete your implementation of `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be answered is to add the logcat(if you use Eclipse) of your problem.

getApplicationContext() return null because you made the method and make it return null. First get the context of the activity where the intent is. It should be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ParkingInfo._longitude", _longitude);
```

And then you should start the intent:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

For more info: [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: not working ,throws this msg

The constructor Intent(ParkingInfo, Class<MainActivity>) is undefined

Comment: @N.Nihar yes it will coz its not a Activity class and needs activity context

Answer (score 0):

remove your getApplicationContext() implementation. You need to call startActivity(intent1) method after setting the intent.

```
try
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(sd.toString()); 

            _longitude=getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

            exif.saveAttributes();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("ParkingInfo._longitude", _longitude);

            mContext.startActivity(intent1);

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Edit:**

pass an Activity object to the constructor of this java class. Have a member variable of type Context in this. Set `this.mContext=context`, then call `mContext.startActivity(intent1)` from your try-catch block. For example:

```
class YourJavaClass{

Context mContext;

public YourJavaClass(Context context)
{
this.mContext=context;
}

}
```

Suppose you are instantiating this class inside an Activity, then instantiate your java class like this:

YourJavaClass object1=new YourJavaClass(this);

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. extend Application class (see: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)
2. create a method like this:

   ```
      public void startMainActivity(String _longitude){

     Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

     intent1.putExtra("ParkingInfo._longitude", _longitude); 

     startActivity(intent1);

   }
   ```
3. call startMainActivity(longitude) from your java class